# Old PCs won't run XNA, what is recommended for creating simple 2D games?

Tags: c#, directx, 2d

I've learnt to code in C# and XNA making 2D games, and wanted to make some little games to use at work (I'm a teacher), but the work PCs have integrated graphics cards which as I discovered means XNA won't run.

I would just like some advice on what route to go down on making my games for old PCs. My first thought was to just tell a windows form to draw my sprites, but that seems a horrible way to proceed. Next idea: learn basic operation of DirectX - 2D only. This is very much new to me and I'd love some general advice before hurling myself down a dead end.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why wont XNA run on integrated cards? my laptop run its fine (Not Hi-def Profile) but REACH. and it uses an integrated Intel chipset.

Comment: XNA should work on old/integrated graphics cards, admittedly not as well as it would on a dedicated card. Your alternatives are to use GDI+ (not really designed for game design), or Direct2D (you will need to use something like SlimDX, or alternatively "roll-your-own" DIrect2D wrapper for .NET)

Comment: also, why didn't it work? most likely you don't have the Runtime installed, as its a school network, all the programs are probably stored and used over a network of some kind, i imagine you don't have the .NET 4.0 framework or the XNA Redistributable installed.

Comment: Alex, the PCs are basically standalone not networked or protected, I do have XNA and .NET framework installed (I'm running programs on there using XNA input but not grpahics) and the schools with nice new PCs it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to create 2D games.  You can use a few libraries:

- SDL: http://www.libsdl.org/
- DirectX: http://www.directxtutorial.com/
- OpenGL: http://www.glprogramming.com/red/

Some really nice frameworks/engines to consider:

- Ogre3D: http://www.ogre3d.org/
- Unity: http://unity3d.com/
- UDK: http://www.unrealengine.com/udk/

It's a broad question so I'm only offering resources for research.  The complexity of your end-result and your personal coding preferences will dictate which route you choose.  SDL is probably your best bet for a 2D game as that is what it's built for.

Comment: Agree; for simple 2D graphics, SDL is about as easy to use as you're going to find.

Comment: I would suggest not doing UDK. That is primarily a 3D engine, and the learning curve is sort of high.

Comment: Thank you for helpful and considerate answer Mike.

Comment: if and when you are comfortable with 2D logistics you could go really nuts and try a 2.5D isometric approach! =D

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is introduce the pupils to the fundamentals of programming and not just C# programming, then I recommend Construct2 or Scratch as free solutions. There are other easy-to-use commercial game programming tools out there as well.

UPDATE: I just saw your comment on the other answer about just wanting to make fun 2d games for the class. I recommend [Construct2](http://www.scirra.com) then. It is really easy and quick to make small 2D games and should work with an integrated graphics card. They have a free version.

Comment: Thanks Juan, but I want to be doing the coding myself - the point is to learn more c# and have fun. I don't want a code-free gamemaker like Construct. Thanks all the same

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must understand for what exact aims you want to use DirectX?

To make a lesson for pupils?

Then you shouldn't start with DirectX ( and frameworks, which are based on DirectX like XNA ), because:

DirectX is based on technology which named COM ( component object model ) and for the better understanding of 3D graphics , it's not the best start.

Maybe, XNA is miles easier and left you free from understanding the base of DirectX architecture, but even with XNA you will work with 3D file formats, where 3D models are prepared in specialized matrix format and also your pupil will learn some from multi-threading  ( and it's another subject ).

First of all, they must understand the difference between CPU && GPU and how does 3D models render in screen.

Do your pupils understand rotation matrices, transformation matrices and etc...
Do they understand the base of geometry?
Do they understand how to differentiate some figure?

There are few base subjects before people begin to learn DirectX and etc... Because it's the base which helps in future not to make bugs and etc

If you want to make Hello-World apps and show it to your pupil, just give them links to the tutorials and books in web.

If you want your pupil be more clever at it you must prepare with some subjects, which are far from such subjects like plain programming or maths.

Comment: I'm not teaching programming, sorry. Just making silly little 2D games to make class more fun (an excuse to do more fun programming!). It's me that's learning here..

Comment: @MrPie if you want more fun for your pupil and forget about XNA and look at Blender 3D and its independent game project http://www.blender.org/gamekit/ , here you can build fun 3D games without any bit of knowledge in developing or math

Comment: Also 2D only.. and I know loads about maths ^^

Comment: Rotation matrices and another are in 2d graphics , aren't they? and they may to learn much in differential geometry if they would like to make 2d games like stickman.

Comment: Oleg, I am not teaching programming or making games in class. I am making games at home for my education and amusement then playing them in class. Sorry for the mix-up.